# Binding data to front-end with React.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, api

I am very new with the react.js library. I am trying to make a simple CRUD application.

I have made a file called `dataprovider.js`

```
export function getCrudData() {
    axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/fearcoder')
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({ githubdata: response.data });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
}
```

I have imported this file in `crudexample.js` and called the method like this:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        dataprovider.getCrudData();
    }
```

When I open Google dev tools with F12 I can see the github data so that's working fine.

Now I want to **bind** this data and I did it like this:

```
  <td>{githubdata.bio}</td>
```

I get the following error in my google dev tools

> 'githubdata' is not defined  no-undef

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your service should **not** be calling setState, you've coupled it to the component.

Comment: Not to discourage you or anything, but I suggest you to read the [ReactJS documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) and start with something simple first. Especially the ReactJS lifecycle is important to understand. Best of luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can write the code as follows :**

***dataProvider.js***

```
export function getCrudData() {
  return axios
    .get("https://api.github.com/users/fearcoder")
    .then(response => {
      return response;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

***crudeExample.js***

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      githubdata: ""
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    getCrudData().then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.setState({ githubdata: res.data });
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { githubdata } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <div>{githubdata.url}</div>
      </>
    );
  }
```

Look at the demo for better clarification.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/upbeat-leftpad-isrm5

:))

Comment: Happy to help. ;))

Comment: You should also `import` dataProvider.js in crudeExample.js

Comment: It is getting imported. You can see codesandbox's link for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
constructor() {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        githubdata: "" // Define githubdata.
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/fearcoder')
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({ githubdata: response.data });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
}
```

Render:

```
<td>{this.state.githubdata.bio}</td>
```

---

[componentDidMount()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

Comment: Hi Daan thanks for your time! Your solution is working but I want my HTTP request in a seperate file. Something like this: `componentDidMount() { this.dataprovider.getCrudData(); }`

Comment: You could put it in a seperate file and [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) it. You could also put it as a function inside your Component. I usually only use `componentDidMount()` to asynchronically fetch (initial) data, so I prefer to keep it all inside there.

Answer (score 0):

`githubdata` is defined in `state`, so use this to access `githubdata`:

`this.state.githubdata`

Comment: thanks for your time! I get the following error TypeError: Cannot read property 'githubdata' of null –

Comment: This is because the component `states` is not yet initialized. And why don't you put this `dataprovider.getCrudData()` in lifecycle method `componentDidMount` as this is the best place for make requests.

Comment: you mean something like this? `componentDidMount() {
        this.dataprovider.getCrudData();
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<td>{this.state.githubdata.bio}</td>
```

Comment: thanks for your time! I get the following error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'githubdata' of null**

Comment: can you please show me the githubdata? maybe it is empty.

Comment: past the following link in your browser: https://api.github.com/users/fearcoder

I get also an error now with TypeError: _this.setState is not a function

Comment: You need to assign data of that API to component's state then it'll be accessible to you hope this will help you.